# How do I pass the current item in a for loop to a method in vue.js 2?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am building (as an exercise) a shopping cart in vue.js 2. I have my shop items and order items stored in my vue data array and a button rendered in a for loop for each shop item to add the item to the order (ex. push).

Here is the section of code that houses my list of items from my shop array in my vue data:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Shop</legend>
    <section v-if="shop">
        <article v-for="(item, index) in shop">
            <header><h1>{{ item.title }}</h1></header>
            <p>{{ item.description }}</p>
            <footer>
                <ul>
                    <li>${{item.price}}</li>
                    <!-- find a way to set input name -->
                    <li><label>Quantity <input type="number" name=""></label></li>
                    <li><button v-on:click="addItemToOrder($event)">Add to Order</button></li>
                </ul>
            </footer>
        </article>
    </section>
    <p v-else>No Items to Display</p>
</fieldset>
```

here is my vue element:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#my-order',
    data:{
        'shop':[
            {
                'title':'Website Content',
                'description':"Order your Website content by the page. Our search-engine-optimized web content puts you ahead of the competition. 250 words.",
                'price':25,
                'sku':'web001'
            },
            {
                'title':'Blog Post',
                'description':"We write blog posts that position your website as a go-to resource for expert knowlegde.",
                'price':50,
                'sku':'blog001'
            },
            {
                'title':'Twitter Post'
            },
            {
                'title':'Product Description'
            }
        ],
        'customizations':null,
        'order':{
            'items':null,
            'total':null
        },
        'customer':null,
        'payment':null
    },
    methods:{
        addItemToOrder: function(){
          /* Here is where I need to append the item to the cart */
        }
    }
})
```

How do I pass the item in the `for` loop to the order (eg: append it to order.items)?

Answer (score 6):

You just need to pass the `item` in as a parameter to the function.

```
v-on:click="addItemToOrder(item)"
```

Then you can use it your Vue component

```
addItemToOrder: function(item){
    this.order.items.push(item);
}
```

Make sure you initialize `order.items` to an empty array inside your components `data` so that you can push to it.

```
'order':{
     'items': [],
     'total': 0
},
```

In general, it is a good idea to initialize your data to the correct data type if you know what it will be.

Comment: Not working. I've even tried passing a string directly in `this.order.items.push('hello')` to no avail. Interestingly, `alert('hello')` works.

Comment: It might not be working because you need to initialize `items` to an empty array inside your `data`. You can't push anything to `null`. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is a bit late however in case anyone else happens across this thread...

You need to pass in the event as well as the item

in your vue code

```
someMethod : function(e, item){}
```

in your html

```
<a v-on:click="someMethod($event, $data)"></a>
```

Comment: Hello thanks this helped me out but can you please explain what does the $event do is it some kind of trigger for change?

Comment: @user3808955 the event is the click event, its the same if you registered a click handler for a dom element, the event would be passed to the listener.